# Codesign not working "Timestamp service not available"

Tags: macos

I am new to the forums, so please be patient with me. I am having an issue with an app that we are working on and appreciate any suggestions or assistance.

We have multiple build machines that we are running, all but 1 are running 10.8. The other one is running 10.7.4.

When we codesign the app on the 10.7.4 system, we have no issues. When we attempt to codesign on the 10.8 systems, we get the error "Timestamp service is not available". The odd thing is that this only started happening about a couple of weeks ago. I do not believe this is a firewall issue, as I have two machines sitting beside me and are running the codesign from my location (10.7.4 machine and a 10.8 machine).

I am running the command: codesign -s "Developer ID Applciation: " /path/to/app.

Now I know there is a workaround: --timestamp=none, but that is not what we are looking to use. I would rather fix the issue than just use a workaround, that most people admit is not a good fix.

Again, I appreciate any assistance! 
D

Comment: I was getting this issue when the internet connection on my machine was having some issues. So i suggest you to check your internet connection

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and it was caused by my network settings not being correct. Specifically there wasn't a dns server setup which meant it couldn't reach a network time server.